# Is there any idiom way to cast between `unique_ptr<T>*` and `unique_ptr<const T>*`?

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I have an array of type `shared_ptr<T>` (or `unique_ptr<T>`). I want to use this array as a parameter for a function which will not modify its contents, so I want the input parameter type to be `shared_ptr<const T> const*`.

```cpp
void process_something(
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>& out,
  std::shared_ptr<const T> const* in,
  size_t n_in
);

int main() {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> data_in, data_out;
  // ... got data_in from somewhere

  // type mismatch:
  // where `data_in.data()` is `std::shared_ptr<T>*`
  //       `in` is `std::shared_ptr<const T> const*`
  process_something(
    data_out,
    data_in.data(), 
    data_in.size()
  );
  return 0;
}
```

I am concerned that `reinterpret_cast` may lead to undefined behavior. I wonder if there is an idiomatic way to cast between `shared_ptr<T>` into `shared_ptr<const T>` or `T const*`.

I would like to avoid any extra memory copying and allocation.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`std::experimental::propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) might interest you.

Comment: Idiomatic way is to pass by value - it will [just work](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/doMnofejW)

Comment: Please don't describe your code, show it instead.

Answer (score 3):

Probably to new of a feature to be idiomatic, but you could use [`std::views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view):

```
void g(int& v)
{
    std::cout << "non-const " << v << '\n';
}

void g(int const& v)
{
    std::cout << "const " << v << '\n';
}

template<class T>
void f(T const& view)
{
    for (auto& e : view)
    {
        g(e);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> a[10];

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = std::make_unique<int>(i);
    }

    f(a | std::views::transform([](std::unique_ptr<int> const& e) -> int const& { return *e; }));
}
```

You could of course also use `std::unique_ptr<int>::get` to transform to a raw pointer instead, if the `std::unique_ptr`s could be empty.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everybody who commented or answered this question.

The issue I'm facing comes from the fact that `const` for pointers in C++ behaves differently for the pointer itself and for the contents it refers to. Essentially, `const std::unique_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<const T>` are distinct.

In contrast to Rust, where `const PointerLike<T>` propagates `const` to the `T`, C++ does not offer this out of the box. As @Jarod42 said, the C++ Standard Library experimentally provides `std::experimental::propagate_const` which does the same, but as it's experimental, it wouldn't be advisable to use it production code.

However, drawing inspiration from the aforementioned, I can create a simple custom wrapper class that propagates `const` to the pointer's value. Here's a rough example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class MyPtr
{
public:
    MyPtr(T* ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}
    
    T* get() { return ptr_; }
    const T* get() const { return ptr_; }

private:
    T* ptr_;
};
```

This class propagates const-ness from the wrapper to the underlying pointer so there is no need to use `MyPtr<const T>` any more.